# is there a isnull or ifnull function in doctrine?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm, isnull

I am looking for a function in doctrine for converting null values to specified default values. So IsNull(A, B) should return B if A is null, A otherwice. Has doctrine such a function?

Comment: Why don't you write it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about grabbing null values from an object, write a method in your entity

```
<?php
// Entities/SomeEntity.php

class Foo
{
    private $a;

    private $b;

    // ...
    // Your getters and setters are here
    // ... 

    public function myNullFunction()
    {
       if($this->a === null AND $this->b !== null)
       {
           return $this->b;
       }
       elseif($this->b === null && $this->a !== null)
       {
           return $this->a;
       }
       else
       {
          // ... Do something if both are null
       }
    }
}
```

You can then use the function whenever you have loaded your object(s)

```
$foo = $some_repository->getFooObject();

// The function returning a value that is a or b
$bar = $foo->myNullFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following project which contains some MSSQL functions for doctrine:
https://github.com/naprstek/doctrine-functions